# Is it possible to debug an input?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails and I have an index page that has an input button to read a file. My code to read the file is in Java Script. Is it possible to debug an input button so I can see the steps of my JS code? Because every time I try to debug it when clicking on the input button it shows me something totally different.

Comment: Do you mean debug a click handler? Sure, same as any other JS.

Comment: I used it like this guy used on the video https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript but didnt work as expected

Comment: It takes me to a jQuery thing

Comment: If you step into jQuery code, that kind of makes sense. Consider putting a breakpoint in *your* code.

Comment: I cant even explain it well

Comment: Hmmm...... the thing is that when I go to my ```sources```>```Event listener breakpoint```>```mouse```>```click``` and click my input button to select my file I cant even se my JS code

Comment: You can put `console.log()` in your JS code, or add `debugger`

Comment: There are... in each ```ìf``` and ```else```I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try use `debugger` command aka The debugger Keyword
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp
if you use this keyword, for example in chrome appear the console and you can execute line each one other and saw all the behavior.